# how to find coordinates of an HTML button or image, cross browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There was a thread on this in comp.lang.javascript recently where
victory was announced but no code was posted:

On an HTML page how do you find the lower left corner coordinates of an element (image or button, say)
reliably across browsers and page styles?  The method advocated in "Ajax in Action" (copy I have) doesn't seem to work in IE under some circumstances.  To make the problem easier, let's assume we can set the global document style to be "traditional" or "transitional" or whatever.

Please provide code or a pointer to code please (a complete function that works on all browsers) -- don't just say "that's easy" and blather about what traversing the DOM -- if I want to read that kind of thing I'll go back to comp.lang.javascript.  Please scold me if this is a repeat and point me to the solution -- I did try to find it.

Comment: Holy (*&^.  I just looked at the jquery solution: add a hidden element to the DOM containing every conceivable tag and then reverse engineer the geometry conventions.  The web is truly amazing place!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience, the only sure-fire way to get stuff like this to work is using [JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS) (don't be afraid, it's just an external script file you have to include). Then you can use a statement like

```
$('#element').position()
```

or

```
$('#element').offset()
```

to get the current coordinates, which works excellently across any and all browsers I've encountered so far.

Comment: 30k for that?  Well, at least I can look and try to see how they implemented it -- assuming I can find an uncompressed source.

Comment: I just had a look at the JQuery source and the functions seem to be heavily interdependent. Too much so to extract just a few lines of code (at least for my taste). 

I usually hate people who do this, but I'm going to go ahead and become one now: JQuery will save you a lot of worries across the board and 30k is not really that much data for something that's going to be cached across requests anyway. Take it from someone who generally hates frameworks ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I found this Solution from the web... This Totally Solved my Problem.
Please check this link for the origin.
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

```
/** This script finds the real position, 
 * so if you resize the page and run the script again, 
 * it points to the correct new position of the element.
 */
function findPos(obj){
   var curleft = 0;
   var curtop = 0;

   if (obj.offsetParent) {
      do {
         curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
         curtop += obj.offsetTop;
      } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

      return {X:curleft,Y:curtop};
   }
}
```

Works Perfectly in Firefox, IE8, Opera (Hope in others too)
Thanks to those who share their knowledge...
Regards,

**ADynaMic**

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this, works for both IE and Firefox.

```
var Target = document.getElementById('SomeID');
var Pos = findPos(Target);

AnotherObj = document.getElementById('AnotherID');
AnotherObj .style.top  = Pos[1] + "px";
AnotherObj .style.left = Pos[0] + "px";

//------------------------------------
function findPos(obj) {
//----------------------------------------
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return [curleft,curtop];
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned, this does not work consistently.  It may be that if I use "strict" html or whatever that it will start working.  Please inform if that is the trick.  The jquery library seems to indicate that you also need to take things like margins into account, which aren't handled by the above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var elm = document.getElementById('foo');
var point = {x:0,y:elm.offsetHeight}; // Change to y:0 to get the top-left

while (elm)
{
    // This will get you the position relative to the absolute container,
    // which is what you need for positioning an element within it
    if (elm.style.position == 'absolute')
        break;

    point.x += elm.offsetLeft;
    point.y += elm.offsetTop;

    elm = elm.offsetParent;
}
```

Comment: Sure <a href=http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/docs/W.intro>http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/docs/W.intro</a>.  If I try to position the footnotes using that algorithm on IE they show up off the page to the right.

Comment: Hmm it actually looks ok to me.  It's hard to read your HTML but I notice you're using position:absolute, which could screw things up.  I've modified the code - give that a try

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery:

```
var jq = $('#yourElement');
var position = jq.offset();
alert('x: ' + position.left + ', y: ' + position.top);

var bottomLeftPixelPosition =
    { left: position.left, top: position.top + jq.height() - 1; };
```