# How to get pixel's index from image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, get, coordinate

I wanna make the ball bounce when it hit the board. So I have to get the board pixels to make it bounce when the ball hit the board. I tried this way but it didn't works.
Here is my code
Javascript code

```
var xboard = document.getElementById(board)
var movx = parseInt(xboard.style.left)
```

Image code

```
<img id="board" style="z-index: 0; left: 300;position: absolute; top: 600px" align=baseline border=0 hspace=0 src="design/board.gif">
```

When I tried to get the pixels by

```
alert(movx)
```

It said "Undefined" at the alert box.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: here is some discussion how to achieve it [Coordinates][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829252/how-to-find-coordinates-of-an-html-button-or-image-cross-browser

Comment: here is some discussion how to achieve it [Coordinates][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829252/how-to-find-coordinates-of-an-html-button-or-image-cross-browser

Comment: It said that we must use JQuery. But what I have to do is make it with javascript, the lecturer said I couldn't use JQuery

Comment: what do you mean? I'm not understand

Comment: See my answer it is with javascript not jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method gives you the coordinates of control passed

```
<img id="board" style="z-index: 0; left: 300;position: absolute; top: 600px" align=baseline border=0 hspace=0 src="design/board.gif">

function findPos(obj){
var curleft = 0;
var curtop = 0;

if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
        curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
       } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

    return {X:curleft,Y:curtop};
}
}

findPos(document.getElementById('board'));
alert(curleft);
alert(curtop);
```

For more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829252/how-to-find-coordinates-of-an-html-button-or-image-cross-browser)

Comment: so I have to load the function findPos in body? if yes, what should I write in the parameter?
<body onLoad="findPos(what should I write here)">

Comment: put  <script language="javascript"> //paste all javascript here</javascript> just before the ending tag of body, and please read some book on javascript....

Comment: @Adil The OP has just started to read books `"...the lecturer said..."` :).

Comment: Did you make it? If this post helped you then you may accept it so that it can help others

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to declare the position with px:

```
left: 300px
```

Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/p2gRq/

Comment: @greenthunder make sure you are calling alert after the DOM has finished - just place the script before closing the BODY tag.

Comment: I put the script in the head, not in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an actual element instead of it's `id`.

Change this:

```
var xboard = document.getElementById(board);
```

to:

```
var xboard = document.getElementById('board');
```

And make sure you're not trying to access `board` before it exists.

Comment: Do you have the variable declarations and that `alert()` in the same function? What is the exact error message? Is it possible to see the whole code here or in the jsFiddle?

Comment: Nope, I put alert in another function. The error message said "Undefined"

Comment: Hm... I think it's your alert-box saying `Undefined`, if that really is all the text in the box. Anyway, you're having a scope-issue. Declaring variables with `var` limits them to be accessible in that one function only. A quick fix is to make `movx` global by removing `var`. Learn more about the scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2C_variables%2C_and_literals#Variable_scope