# How to get coordinates of a button in a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am looking for a way to get the coordinates of e.g. a button in a browser. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find coordinates of an HTML button or image, cross browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829252/how-to-find-coordinates-of-an-html-button-or-image-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0):

To get the coordinates of a button in a browser, you need to first write a selector to get the particular button you're interested in finding the coordinates for.

```
var button = document.querySelector('button')
```

To get the coordinate, it depends on if you want the coordinates in reference to some other element. If the coordinates were in reference to itself, then it would be as simple as

```
{left: 0, top: 0, bottom:  button.offsetHeight, right: button.offsetWidth}
```

If you want to have it in reference to a different element like the window for instance, you can recursively traverse the button's parents until the window is reached

```
var top = button.offsetTop;
var left = button.offsetLeft;
var height = button.offsetHeight;
var width = button.offsetWidth;
while(button.offsetParent && button.offsetParent != window){
    button = button.offsetParent;
    top += button.offsetTop;
    left += button.offsetLeft;
}
var bottom = top + height;
var right = left + width;
return {left: left, top: top, bottom: bottom, right: right}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use as following code to get Co-ordinates of the button.

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="display" onclick="getCoords()">
<script>
    function getCoords() {
        var mainEvent = event ? event : window.event;

        alert("This button click occurred at: X(" + mainEvent.screenX + ") 
            and Y(" + mainEvent.screenY +       ")");
    }
</script>
```

Here is the working example:http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/1692/